# SVGs from file aren't loading on Angular App

Tags: angular, svg

I'm using some svgs into my Angular app, but they don't seem to be loading despite the component is loading properly (checked via inspector).

First of all I have an **svg file called SaltyWebFont.svg** containing **multiple** svg images. The location is in assets/icons/SaltyWebFont.svg, I think the root directory is not the problem as the app can load images contained under the same directories. This file is accessed via its specific component **svg-icon.component.html**:

```
<svg>
  <use attr.xlink:href="assets/icons/SaltyWebFont.svg#{{icon}}"></use>
</svg>
```

The ts file linked to this view is **svg-icon.component.ts**:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'salty-svg-icon',
  templateUrl: './svg-icon.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./svg-icon.component.sass']
})
export class SvgIconComponent {
  @Input() icon: string;
}
```

Which is imported into **home.module.ts**, the component in which I want the svgs to show:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';
import { SvgIconComponent } from '../shared/components/svg-icon/svg-icon.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HomeComponent,
    SvgIconComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ]
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

and **home.component.ts**:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.sass']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

and **home.component.html**:

```
<salty-svg-icon icon="BAN001" class="icon"></salty-svg-icon>
```

I can't find the svg loaded in the html dom under head or body, but I can find the tag from the component has been properly loaded:

```
<salty-svg-icon _ngcontent-ewr-c4="" class="icon" icon="BAN001" _nghost-ewr-c5="" ng-reflect-icon="BAN001"> 
 <svg _ngcontent-ewr-c5=""><use _ngcontent-ewr-c5="" xlink:href="assets/icons/SaltyWebFont.svg#BAN001"></use></svg>
</salty-svg-icon>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Is this also an issue with ng serve? If so, maybe you can try /assets (add slash) in the svg href.

Comment: I tried, it didn't work, and it might have to do with my angular overall project or ng serve, as I've put some svgs inside assets folders with pngs, looked with the inspector into Source and I can only see the trace to folders with pngs, but inside no svgs.

Comment: I finally had to import them as icon libraries, so I don't think this issue will be solved before it's closed